# How to convert DataSnapshot of firbease to json file or how to retrive firebase database as json file

Tags: android, arrays, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrive json data from firebase, so how could i retrive it from firebase or how could i convert firebase datasnapshot to json format.

Comment: try something yourself and post some code.

Comment: post your datasnapshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a custom class/object or Map do try like this...

```
List<JSONObject> obj=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Your_Path");

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                YourObjectClass cls=childDataSnapshot.getValue(YourObjectClass.class);
JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
jo.put("your variable name",cls.YOUR_KEY);
//Extra properties...
obj.add(jo);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database SDKs don't expose the raw underlying data. If you want the JSON from a `DataSnapshot` you will have to reproduce it in your application code.

Alternatively you can use the REST API to get the raw JSON from a location by reading (strictly speaking: firing a HTTP `GET` request against) `https://yourdb.firebaseio.com/path/to/data.json` (the `.json` is crucial here, since it tells Firebase to return the data.

For more on this, see the documentation on [reading data through the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data) and possibly [authenticating REST requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).